# Replace part of string in filename

Tags: rename, filenames

I have several files in a directory ending with 'StringtoReplace'. How can I replace that part of the filename for all the files in the directory with a new string, 'ReplacedString'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace the first instance of "StringtoReplace" with "ReplacedString":

```
for f in *StringtoReplace; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv -- "$f" "${f/StringtoReplace/ReplacedString}"; done
```

This will replace the *last* instance of "StringtoReplace" with "ReplacedString":

```
for f in *StringtoReplace; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv -- "$f" "${f%StringtoReplace}ReplacedString"; done
```